# Importing and exporting components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to ReactNative and am trying to use a component that I'm importing from a file within my workspace and I'm getting this error:

invariant violation: element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I checked to make sure I had my files path right, and I did. I've also exported my class within its file, so I didn't find that to be the problem either. here's what I have in App.js:

```
import ExampleApp from './src/components/ExampleApp';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => ExampleApp);
```

```
and here's what I have in my components file:
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';

export default class ExampleApp extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({barcodes}) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
        <View style={{flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
            style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = {quality: 0.5, base64: true};
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 70,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: What is `name` in your app.json? It must match `App` value you pass to your `registerComponent`

Answer (score 0):

solution: putting export default className; at the bottom of my camera components file solved my problem